# Need Dropbox sample to write text from html form

Tags: javascript, html, dropbox

I'm looking to write text from an html form textarea into my Dropbox account.

While I can get the Dropbox chooser/saver logic to work, I cannot find a way to send the char.stream to make a file. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the Core API. Here's a small example in JavaScript: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/71/writing-a-file-with-the-dropbox-javascript-sdk.